# Get the EntitySet name from an EntityType in EF

Tags: entity-framework

Given an EntityType, such as "Contact", how can I derive from it the name of the EntitySet it would belong to, i.e. the pluralization such as "Contacts"?

Comment: I am guessing you dont have an instance of the object?

Comment: @Nix I also had the same problem, my Type was T param, so there was sure no instance of the object?

Comment: I have to comment and thank you for this, because I ran into the EXACT same issue of 'Contacts' and 'Contact'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you already have an attached entity (obviously you don't need the first line, just use your existing entity):

```
  Contact c = context.Contacts.Where(x => x.blah).FirstOrDefault();
  string setName = c.EntityKey.EntitySetName;
```

Or if you don't:

```
 string className = typeof(Contact).Name
 var container =   
    context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
    string setName = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
                                          where meta.ElementType.Name == className
                                          select meta.Name).First();
```

Comment: Very nice.  I needed this to do additional customization of POCO entities, like adding GetById() methods to all of the entity classes.

Comment: Genius, I've been trying to do this for ages, thanks a lot, +1 for a great answer

Comment: Note that CSpace queries only work when you have connected to the database, so it won't work in scenarios where you just want to query types directly.

Comment: @Nix, could you tell me why the following code has 'EntityKey' nullreference error? entities.CreateObject<T>(typeof(T).Name).EntityKey.EntitySetName

Comment: how bout for entity sets extended class. e.g. Person has db.Persons and Student : Person has db.Students. I can't seem to find Students in BaseEntitySets

Answer (score 6):

This extension may be useful

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string GetEntitySetName<T>(this ObjectContext context)
    {
        string className = typeof(T).Name;

        var container = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
        string entitySetName = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
                                where meta.ElementType.Name == className
                                select meta.Name).First();

        return entitySetName;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
db.AttachTo(db.GetEntitySetName<MyEntityType>(), myEntityInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that works similar to the accepted answer except that this supports a) **proxy types** (for example, if you dynamically get the type of an EF6 entity it could be of type "Contact_1A2B3C4D5E" instead of "Contact") and b) **inheritance** (table-per-type, table-per-hierarchy).

```
private static string GetEntitySetName(ObjectContext objectContext, Type type)
{
    if (objectContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objectContext));
    if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

    EntityContainer container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);

    return container.BaseEntitySets
        .Where(x =>
            (x.ElementType.Name == type.Name) ||
            (x.ElementType.Name == type.BaseType?.Name) ||
            (x.ElementType.Name == type.BaseType?.BaseType?.Name)
        )
        .Select(x => x.Name)
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new ArgumentException($"Specified type is not an entity type.", nameof(type));
}
```