# EF get dbset name in runtime from Type

Tags: entity-framework, type-conversion, dbcontext, typeof, dbset

Purpose:
I need to get the name of the dbset name of the entity
typeof(UserAccount) = "UserAccounts".
But in runtime I need a common type for the loop and therefor do not know example "UserAccount".
Only the "name" from typeof?

I have created an DbContext with some entities.
I have been googling for some time but it do not seem to be working for me because of the Type converting?

Please see my method **GetDbSetName** in the bottom of this description.

I am pretty new at this EF stuff - so please help med with my issue as described below ;-)

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set;}
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAccountRole> UserAccountRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Defined a list of Type to control the output:

```
public static List<Type> ModelListSorted()
{
    List<Type> modelListSorted = new List<Type>();
    modelListSorted.Add(typeof(UserRole));
    modelListSorted.Add(typeof(UserAccountRole));
    modelListSorted.Add(typeof(UserAccount));
    return modelListSorted;
}
```

The problem is below using **Type** - If I use "UserAccount" it Works and I get "UserAccounts".
But I do not have the "UserAccount" in runtime as I am in a loop with a serie of types.
I do only have the Type list giving the e

```
public static loopList()
{
    List<Type> modelListSorted = ModelListSorted();
    foreach (Type currentType in modelListSorted)
    {
         string s = DataHelper.GetDbSetName(currentType, db);
    } 
}
```

**HERE IS THE METHOD GIVING ME THE CHALLANGES ;-)**
Meaning not compiling.
saying I am missing a assembly?
I know it is pretty pseudo but can this be done smoothly?

```
public static string GetDbSetName(Type parmType, MyEntities db)
{
    string dbsetname = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<parmType>().EntitySet.Name;
    return dbsetname;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge here is that two reflection steps are involved, one to invoke the generic `CreateObjectSet` method and one to get the `EntitySet` from the result. Here's a way to do this:

First, the method:

```
string GetObjectSetName(ObjectContext oc, MethodInfo createObjectSetMethodInfo,
                        Type objectSetType, Type entityType)
{
    var objectSet = createObjectSetMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
                                             .Invoke(oc, null);
    var pi = objectSetType.MakeGenericType(entityType).GetProperty("EntitySet");
    var entitySet = pi.GetValue(objectSet) as EntitySet;
    return entitySet.Name;
}
```

As you see, I first get the `ObjectSet` by invoking the `MethodInfo` representing the generic method `CreateObjectSet<T>()`. Then I find the `PropertyInfo` for the `EntitySet` property of the generic type `ObectSet<T>`. Finally, I get this property's value and the name of the obtained `EntitySet`.

To do this, I first get a `MethodInfo` for `CreateObjectSet<>()` (the one without parameters) and the `ObjectSet<>` type

```
var createObjectSetMethodInfo = 
    typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethods()
                         .Single(i => i.Name == "CreateObjectSet" 
                                   && !i.GetParameters().Any());

var objectSetType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ObjectContext))
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Single(t => t.Name == "ObjectSet`1");
```

In `GetObjectSetName` their generic parameters are specified by a concrete entity type, which is done by these "MakeGeneric..." methods.

```
var oc = (dbContextInstance as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
var entityType = typeof(UserRole);
var name = GetObjectSetName(oc, createObjectSetMethodInfo, objectSetType, entityType);
```

In EF 6 these should be the `using`s:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
using System.Linq
using System.Reflection
```

Comment: Hi @GertArnold. Thanks for your reply - Nice and simple thinking!
I am getting error at the line: `var objectSet = createObjectSetMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(oc, null);`
Exception message: {"Object does not match target type."}

Comment: I think the issue is around here: `var oc = (dbContextInstance as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;`
As we expect System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext but are getting System.Data.Entity.Core.ObjectContext?
- But I can not figure how to resolve it?

Comment: Also this line `var entitySet = pi.GetValue(objectSet) as EntitySet;`
Exception message: {"Object does not match target type."}
can you also help resolving this along with the previous?

Comment: I had the Framework 6.1.1 in my references?
Now I have removed it and installed it again.
I can now compile your code with not changes
i have following usings:
System.Linq;
System.Reflection;
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
System.Data.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

Comment: But this line `var entitySet = pi.GetValue(objectSet) as EntitySet;` is returning null.
when debugging i can see the vaules in objectSet used for the GetValue method?

Comment: That should be in `System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm`. I'll add the usings to my answer, because they are very confusing since EF changed them in v6.

Comment: YES! It works beautiful. Thank you so much for your experience and patience :-)

Comment: here is better approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686419/get-the-entityset-name-from-an-entitytype-in-ef